# Math books with interesting topics for a college freshman

Tags: book-recommendation

I am an engineering student just starting college (I am also a new member of this community). Lately, I have been really getting into math (I liked math before but now I am even considering changing majors). I have been consuming a lot of math content on youtube and internet forums and would like to read books about interesting math topics as well. My main concern is finding a book at my math level that doesn't oversimplify topics to the point of just brushing them off but that doesn't get too complex to even understand either.

If anyone here has any recommendations on any topics that yall have found interesting let me know. I personally would love to learn more about topology, number theory, and holomorphic dynamics; but any other topics are great as well. :)))

Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Complex Analysis--won't be necessary for engineering (other than coursework) but very fundamental....could I recommend Physics instead if you like Math?

Comment: Complex analysis looks cool, and yeah I’m down for some physics too